# Modifying model data before sending response

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am working on a back-end that needs to re-calculate the price based on user-specific currency.

I fetch all required records from the database as following:

```
 $tasks = Task::with([
            'images' => function($query){},
            'price' => function($query){},
            'user' => function($query){ $query->with('images');},
        ])->whereDoesntHave('tasksState', function($query) use ($user){
            $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
            $query->where('state', '<>', 0);
        })->where('id', '>', $offset)->where('user_id', '<>', $user->id)->take($limit)->get();
```

Task's price model consists of currency and value attributes.

Then I iterate through $tasks and re-calculate the price based on the user-specific currency:

```
foreach ($tasks as $k => $task){
            $price = $task->price->value;
            $price = $price * $rate->getValue();
            $tasks[$k]->price = $price;
            //$task->price = $price;
        }
```

After inspecting the tasks, all price are re-calculated correctly.

However when I subsequently serialize $tasks and send it as a response, it contains the data as they were fetched from the database - no re-calculated prices.

Does anybody where is the problem? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators) for this.

Create following function in `Task` Model

```
public function getNewPriceAttribute($value)
{
  ...// do your processing here
}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
$task->new_price;
```

After creating the accessor, add the attribute name to the [`appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) property on the `Task` model.

```
 protected $appends = ['new_price'];
```

Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON representations.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're serializing the data anyway, you [can first convert collection into an array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray) and work it as with an array:

```
$tasks->toArray();
```

In this case you'll be able to override original data as you've tried to accomplish with `foreach` loop.

As alternative, you could [create a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) which will add `calculated_price` property to the collection.

Comment: Thank you! I had to pick between two correct answers and @Amit Gupta's had it more complete. I gave you at least vote up :-)